# Error in SQLPLUS declare block

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, sqlplus

I am getting an error in the declare block. I have pasted it below the code.

```
function XYZ
{
        sqlplus -s $DB_USR/$DB_USR$pwd_suffix@$SID
        set timing off
        set serveroutput on size 10000
        set feedback off
        spool logname_$sid.out

        variable ex_code number
        whenever sqlerror exit 1
        begin
                :ex_code :=0;
        end;
        /


        declare

         l_cnt number := 0;
         l_sql varchar2(4000) := '';
         l_tmp_name varchar2(100) := '';
    some more code...

}
```

> ./XYZ.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>      ./XYZ.sh: line 26: `         l_sql varchar2(4000) := '';'
>      -bash-3.2$

Can somebody tell me what is causing the problem?

Comment: What's this code exactly? PL/SQL or bash?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a here-document, assuming `sqlplus` is reading from standard input:

```
function XYZ
{
        sqlplus -s $DB_USR/$DB_USR$pwd_suffix@$SID <<-EOF
        set timing off
        set serveroutput on size 10000
        set feedback off
        spool logname_$sid.out

        variable ex_code number
        whenever sqlerror exit 1
        begin
                :ex_code :=0;
        end;
        /


        declare

         l_cnt number := 0;
         l_sql varchar2(4000) := '';
         l_tmp_name varchar2(100) := '';
        some more code...
        EOF
}
```